# Reset Custom Classes per Unit Test

Tags: python, python-unittest

It is my understanding that every test in a series of unit tests should be completely independent.  As such I am attempting to recreate my custom object with default settings for each test.

However, It seems that subsequent tests are reusing the same objects, even when I use tearDown or del commands.

I created a small example that exhibits the same behavior.

```
class MyClass:

    numbers = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        del self.numbers

    def addNumber(self,newnumber):
        self.numbers += [newnumber]

    def getNumbers(self):
        return self.numbers
```

```
import unittest
from myclass import MyClass

class TestNumbers(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_oneNumbers(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        mc.addNumber(5)
        self.assertListEqual(mc.getNumbers(), [5])
        del mc

    def test_twoNumbers(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        mc.addNumber(5)
        mc.addNumber(6)
        self.assertListEqual(mc.getNumbers(), [5,6])
        del mc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Python myunit.py output

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_twoNumbers (__main__.TestNumbers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\REDACTED\unitexample\myunit.py", line 17, in test_twoNumbers
    self.assertListEqual(mc.getNumbers(), [5,6])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [5, 5, 6] != [5, 6]

First differing element 1:
5
6

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 2:
6

- [5, 5, 6]
?     ---

+ [5, 6]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

shouldn't each instance of MyClass be independent?

Comment: So do you want them to be independent or not?

Comment: You are using a class variable, not an instance variable - is this what you want? In your `__del__`, you probably want to clear the list, e.g. `self.numbers.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

@MrBean-Bremen was correct, I moved the variable to the **init** class to make it an instance variable.  Each instance now keeps their own copy.

I read https://pencilprogrammer.com/python-tutorials/class-and-instance-variables/ to help clarify the difference as well.

ALthough i'm not sure its necessary, but I also clean out the dictionary in my **del**

Comment: In python `del` is almost always unnecessary due to reference counting. Your methods have `mc = MyClass(); del mc`, but the `mc` will die anyway because methods are a scope.